# Download CSV file from browser after making axios call from React to Nodejs Api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have MERN application and I want to download a CSV file on button click. I implemented everything but when I click the button there is no download in browser.

**Axios call**

```
const handleDownloadCsv = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.get('http://localhost:2000/users/admin-panel/csv');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

**NodeJs controller**

```
export const admin_panel_csv = async (req,res) => {
try {

    let __dirname = res.locals.__dirname;

    const myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/documents/admin_csv.csv');

    //myReadStream.pipe(res);
    res.download(__dirname + '/documents/admin_csv.csv')

} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error csv: ',error.message);
    res.status(400).json({msg:error.message});
  }
 }
```

I've tried both createReadStream(with pipe) and res.download(path to file) but non of them seams to work. I am not getting any errors when making this api call through axios. Is there some way to accomplish this without using React libraries.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a reason for `admin_panel_csv` to be async. That will just return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no download prompt in the browser since you are initiating the download via `axios` and not through the browser (e.g., through a `<form>` POST or an `<a>` click).

Change the back-end code back to `res.download` and on the front-end, initiate the download through an `<a>` click:

```
const handleDownloadCsv = () => {
  const tempLink = document.createElement('a')
  tempLink.href = 'http://localhost:2000/users/admin-panel/csv'
  tempLink.click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use js-file-download in React and just :

```
const FileDownload = require('js-file-download');
Axios.get(API_URL + "download")
.then((response) => {
    FileDownload(response.data, 'file.txt');
});
```